# how to extract this kind of data and put them into a nice array?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I got a string like this one:

```
var tweet ="@fadil good:))RT @finnyajja: what a nice day RT @fadielfirsta: how are you? @finnyajja yay";
```

what kind of code should work to extract any words with @ character and also removing any special char at the end of the words? so it would an array like this :

```
(@fadil, @finnyajja, @fadielfirsta, @finnyajja);
```

i have tried the following code :

```
var users = $.grep(tweet.split(" "), function(a){return /^@/.test(a)});
```

it returns this:

```
(@fadil, @finnyajja:, @fadielfirsta:, @finnyajja)
```

there's still colon ':' character at the end of some words. What should I do? any solution guys? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code that is more straightforward than trying to use split:

```
var tweet_text ="@fadil good:))RT @finnyajja: what a nice day RT @fadielfirsta: how are you? @finnyajja yay";

var result = tweet_text.match(/@\w+/g);
```

Comment: wow. It perfectly works! thank you :-). this regex stuff is tough for me. but you just make it looks really simple.

Comment: one more question if you don't mind. what regex should I use to match any word begin with 'http://' in a string. As you guess, I tried to find any URL in a string. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way without changing your current code too much would be to just remove all colons prior to calling split:

```
var users = $.grep(tweet_text.replace(":","").split(" "), function(a){return /^@/.test(a)});
```

You could also write a regex to do all the work for you using `match`.  Something like this:

```
var regex = /@[a-z0-9]+/gi;
var matches = tweet.match(regex);
```

This assumes that you only want letters and numbers, if certain other characters are allowed, this regex will need to be modified.

http://jsfiddle.net/YHM87/